# How to Create Windows Service in .netcoreapp1.0 framework?

Tags: windows-services, asp.net-core

I'm working on a netcoreapp1.0 application , ( my target framework is netcoreapp1.0), i want to create a windows service from this application, lets say it is running every 5 minutes.

The package to use for creating ws is [this one](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WindowsServices), but this package only works on full .net framework which is not appropriate for me, I want a solution which works for .netcoreapp1.0 only.

Is there any solution for my problem?

here is my project.json file :

```
{
 "version": "1.0.0-*",
 "buildOptions": {
 "emitEntryPoint": true
},
"frameworks": {
 "netcoreapp1.0": {
 }
},
"dependencies": {
 "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
   "type": "platform",
   "version": "1.0.0"
 },
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting": "1.0.0",
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WindowsServices": "1.0.0",
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0"
 }
}
```

and here is my program.cs:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var exePath = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName;
        var directoryPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(exePath);

        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(directoryPath)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();

        if (Debugger.IsAttached || args.Contains("--debug"))
        {
            host.Run();
        }
        else
        {
            host.RunAsService();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Look on this https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1386 issue on github for details how you can achieve this. In future this also may be obtained using TopShelf framework , but right now .NET Core support is in progress state (https://github.com/Topshelf/Topshelf/issues/277)

Comment: @Set tnx , but i did read that post before, but i did not find any good solution , i think all of them like me want a solution, am i correct?